# How to make a phone call by clicking on number

Tags: android, phone-call

I have a list view containing numbers. When you click on the number, I want it to make a call, and present a confirmation popup with two options - "Yes" and "No". When I call the following code, it works, but it leaves my application - it should make the call within the application, and, if the user clicks no, the previous screen should appear, and if the user clicks yes, it should call that number. Then, after the call has ended, it should go back to the previous screen. Any ideas?

```
Intent sIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:123434543"));    
startActivity(sIntent);
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: i have added my code above, in the onclick method i am reading the number and using the above 2 line code

Comment: what if you try with `startActivityForResult()` ? And for Yes/No screen call a Alert Dialog on your text click and in that alert YES button call Intent to call with startActivityForResult.

Comment: I think this is default behavior of this code. when call ended it goes back to your application. What do you want you need to show calling screen in your application UI?

Comment: can you please write the code exactly what you want tell me ..

Comment: @Pankaj Kumar: Actually with my code after disconnecting the call it is going to call logs, then if i click on back it is going back to my application.

Comment: @Vamshi do you understand what i said above?

Comment: No that was not different but when I tried its working as you want...

Answer (score 3):

try this::

```
private void callDialog() {
    try {

        dismissProgressDialog();

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        textView.setText("Would u like to do call?");
        textView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        textView.setTextSize(18);

        AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(BusinessList.this);
        dialog.setTitle("");
        dialog.setView(textView);

        dialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + callNo)));

            }
        });
        dialog.setNegativeButton("No", new android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });
        dialog.show();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

when u call plz do not finish activity.
if u want different plz explain more.